# NSTimer causes UIScrollViews to stop scrolling only on iPod Touch 4th gens

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nstimer

I'm using the following code to update my custom drawRects in my UIView subclasses

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:... 
                                         target:...
                                       selector:....
                                       userInfo:...
                                        repeats:...];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The interval is set to run repeatedly every 1/30th of a second to update my UIViews. It seems to work fine, but all of my UIScrollViews stop "bouncing", meaning, if I were to scroll my UIScrollView beyond the content frame bounds, they do not bounce back. This only happens on the iPod touch 4th gens. On my iPad 3rd gen and my iPhone 5, my UIScrollViews bounce back to the content frame.
Any ideas?

Comment: What does the timer fire method do?

Comment: Agreed. And, depending upon what your timer method is doing, you might also consider a [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). By the way, there are limitations on concurrency on older devices (I would have expected problems on 3rd gen), but I would have thought that 4th gen (A4 processor) would have been fine. But the other devices you list are A5, A5X or A6 processors. Are you sure that iPod touch is 4th gen and not 3rd gen?

Comment: @Wain The fire method calls a method: `setNeedsDisplay` on 3 instances. Those 3 instances have a custom drawRect method implemented. The drawRect uses UIBezierPath to draw a stroke circle.

Comment: @Rob 100% sure it is an iPod touch 4th gen.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must rest elsewhere. I tested a simple custom view that draws a circle:

```
@interface CircleView ()

@property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime startTime;

@end

@implementation CircleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CFAbsoluteTime elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.startTime;
    float seconds;
    float fractionsOfSecond = modff(elapsed, &seconds);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width * fabs(fractionsOfSecond - 0.5) * 2.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 10.0, 0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}

@end
```

And I added three of those to a scroll view and started a timer:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *circles;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add three circle views

    CircleView *circle;
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height / 3.0;
    frame.size.height = height;

    self.circles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        circle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:circle];
        self.circles[i] = circle;
        frame.origin.y += height;
    }

    // start timer

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(handleTimer)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)handleTimer
{
    // show the time so I can see the timer in action

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    });
    self.timeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // let's update three circles

    for (UIView *view in self.circles)
        [view setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

And it worked fine on 4th generation iPod Touch. Perhaps you can share some of your code and we can identify the source of the problem.